# Reference request for c*-algebra embedding into the atomic part of its double dual

Tags: reference-request, oa.operator-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

Let $A$ be a C*-algebra. According to operator algebraists, it is well known that $A$ embeds into the atomic part of its double dual in the following sense: if $z$ is the central projection in $A^{**}$ onto its atomic part, then the composition of the embedding $A \hookrightarrow A^{**}$ with multiplication by $z$ yields an embedding $A \hookrightarrow zA^{**}$.

I see how one can prove this, but I need this result in my paper which is not aimed at operator algebraists, so I would like to give a reference. However, I cannot find this in the literature. I looked at Takesaki, Blackadar, Dixmier, Sakai, Kadison-Ringrose, and the closest I got was Definition III.6.35 in Takesaki where he defines the universal atomic representation, but I don't see how the above result immediately follows from this definition or its subsequent results.

Does anyone have a reference for this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are only interested in seeing the statement written down in the literature, then see the first paragraph of the paper *[A Gelfand representation theory for C$^*$-algebras](http://dx.doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1971.39.1)* by C. Akemann. This in turn refers to Dixmier's text *Les C$^*$-algebres et leurs représentations*, page 39, but when I look at the results on that page in the text (about existence of representations of C*-algebras), it would not be apparent how to derive the claim unless one is already familiar with the theory of C$^*$-algebras.

I also just stumbled (via Akemann's earlier paper *[The general Stone-Weierstrass problem](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-1236(69)90015-9)*) upon the following:

*[On the Borel structure of C](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.cmp/1103840557)*-algebras*
by E.B. Davies

Theorem 3.2 of the paper is just a bit more general than what you are asking for, showing that a certain envelope of each C$^*$-algebra embeds in the reduced atomic representation.